# How to select any text and save that text directly in a .txt file in pre-specified folder?

Tags: windows-xp, autohotkey, productivity

How to select any text and save that text directly in a .txt file in specified folder(in script like D:/backup/) and file name (filename.txt) should be asked upon pressing keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ways to go about doing this. The easiest would probably be to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to store it in the clipboard, then write the clipboard contents to a text file:

```
^!p::
path= C:\
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll
Send ^c
clipwait
InputBox, location, save, Enter a filename:
FormatTime, TimeString,,MMM-dd-yyyy
FileAppend, %clipboard%, %path%\%location%-%TimeString%.txt
Clipboard := ClipSaved
ClipSaved=
return
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> will trigger this. Let me know how it works I just hacked it together quickly.

Comment: @john - I want to set path manually in script code and only file name should be asked by dialog-box and extension should be fixed (.txt) with current date as a suffix of file like Filename-currentDate.txt. i want to give only filename and saving file would be like this estillproject-20/jan/10.txt

Comment: John T - Where are you?

Comment: @Jitendra I was asleep then at school, sorry. From what it looks like you want it to also make directories? Or am I mistaken? I've edited the code so you can put the path at the top, where it says `path=`, files will be saved in the format `Filename-Jan-21-2010.txt` if  that's  what you're after?

Comment: sorry it's working i had not created a folder. You are my lifesaver. You are awesome.

Comment: @John T I just started using AHK today and I am searching the net to see all the cool stuff that can be done with it, this is one of the coolest examples I have found so far! +1 John T would you happen to have any other useful AHK code to share?

Comment: @jason my AHK arsenal is quite lengthy, and also contains some personal login information which I don't want to find and dig out, but I keep it in there to make my life a bit easier. If there is a specific category of scripts your looking for, I can send you quite a few, just not my entire file :)  Glad you're enjoying the program though, happy AHKing!

Comment: @John T thanks for responding, and so quiclkly at that!  I do not have a particular, I just started using AHK 3 days ago for the first time, I am a PHP developer so I know quite a bit aout computers in general and I am just shocked that I have never taken the time to see how amazing AHK really is.  I am currently using it just to replace text with shortcuts, other then that I am trying to learn what it is possible of doing, so seeing what others have done with it just gives me ideas and many time like in this example you have posted here

Comment: @John T ...continued from my previous, ran out of character space... things like this example just show me what is possible and I can use stuff like this for something, I would love to see anything you are willing to share and be greatful.   IF you would like to share anything else my email is friendproject@gmail.com   thank you so much =)